Escritura en TXT
estoy teniendo problemas con este codigo, por logica el seek, me posicionaria al comienzo de la linea para que luego escribirla con el dato nuevo, siendo el truncate, para cortar si llegara a ser mas grande que lo original, tampoco estaria escribiendose en el archivo filetemp, que lo estoy usando de prueba
        archivo = ".\Parte_2.txt"
        filetemp = open(".\Temporal.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8")
        try:
            with open(archivo, "a+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.seek(0)
                lines = file.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    study_pk, protocolo, val3, link, estado = line.strip().split(",")
                    estado = download(session, protocolo, study_pk, link, estado)
                    updated_line = f"{study_pk},{protocolo},{val3},{link},{estado}\n"
                    try:
                        file.write(updated_line)
                        print("Escribiendo en: ", os.path.abspath(archivo))
                    except IOError as e:
                        print(f"Error al escribir en el archivo: {e}")
                    filetemp.write(updated_line)
                    
                    print(updated_line)
                
                file.truncate()  
        


En filetemp deberías usar  "w"  y para file.seek() solo lee el archivo

No entendí la pregunta

Me parece que el problema es que estás usando "a+" en open() paraobtener filetemp y para  file.seek(0)

"a+" - Anexar - Abre un archivo para anexarlo, crea el archivo si no
existe. Crea un nuevo archivo o abre un archivo existente para lectura y escritura, y el puntero del archivo se sitúa al final del archivo.

Deberías primero abrir el archivo , para filetemp  :

"w" - Escribir - Abre un archivo para escribir, crea el archivo si no
existe. La w crea un nuevo archivo o trunca un archivo existente,
luego lo abre para escribir; la posición del puntero del archivo al
comienzo del archivo.

y para file usa :

"r+" - Lectura - El modo abre el archivo tanto para lectura como para
escritura. r+ genera un error si el archivo no existe o abre un archivo existente sin truncarlo para lectura y escritura; la posición del puntero del archivo al comienzo del archivo.

Realizael cambio en tu código:
archivo = ".\Parte_2.txt"
        filetemp = open(".\Temporal.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
        try:
            with open(archivo, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.seek(0)
                lines = file.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    study_pk, protocolo, val3, link, estado = line.strip().split(",")
                    estado = download(session, protocolo, study_pk, link, estado)
                    updated_line = f"{study_pk},{protocolo},{val3},{link},{estado}\n"
                    try:
                        file.write(updated_line)
                        print("Escribiendo en: ", os.path.abspath(archivo))
                    except IOError as e:
                        print(f"Error al escribir en el archivo: {e}")
                    filetemp.write(updated_line)
                    
                    print(updated_line)
                
                file.truncate()  
        

